# Xcode8 iOS9 UIAlertController textfield disapear (iOS8&10 is normal)

Tags: uitextfield, ios9, xcode8, uialertcontroller

Xcode 8 iOS9 UIAlertController textfield disappear.
Before migrate from Xcode7 to Xcode8, it don't have any problem while the app running on iOS9.

1. [iOS9 UIAlertController With UITextfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRR5.png)
2. [iOS10 UIAlertController With UITextfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIzzn.png)

Does anyone have this problem?

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"mile" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

```
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:getLocalizationString(@"cancel") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

@weakify(alertController);
@weakify(self);
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:getLocalizationString(@"ok") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    @strongify(alertController);
    @strongify(self);
    UITextField *textField = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
    self.totalMileage = textField.text;
    self.mileageLabel.text = self.totalMileage;
    if (self.start2DriveDateTime&&![self.start2DriveDateTime isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self getRecommendMaintenanceList];
    }
}];
okAction.enabled = (self.totalMileage&&![self.totalMileage isEqualToString:@""]);
[alertController addAction:okAction];


[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
    @strongify(self);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(alertTextFieldDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];
    textField.placeholder = @"mile";
    textField.keyboardType =UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.text = self.totalMileage;
    textField.delegate = self;
}];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "disappear" please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRR5.png
run the app on iOS9 without change any code in xcode 8